# Why is first TableRow null in my CellFactory?

Tags: javafx

I have a working implementation of a `DatePicker` `TableCell`, but I'm experiencing a `NullPointerException` when my `CellFactory` attempts to retrieve the `TableRow`.

The exception does not appear to affect the actual functionality in any way, but I do not understand what is causing it.

For brevity, here is just the `CellFactory` implementation (full MCVE below, but maybe this is enough for you to see my error):

```
    colDatePaid.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Bill, LocalDate>() {

        final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {

                System.out.println(getTableRow()); // <-- This prints 'null' only once upon execution
                Bill bill = (Bill) getTableRow().getItem();

                if (item == null || bill.isDateChanged()) {
                    bill.datePaidProperty().bind(datePicker.valueProperty());
                    setGraphic(datePicker);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(new Label(bill.getDatePaid().toString()));
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

The `println()` method gives the following output as well as the NPE:

```
null
TableRow@47e536dc[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
TableRow@1345fc2c[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
TableRow@44dfbc27[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
TableRow@5c091f1[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
TableRow@3b50e9f5[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
TableRow@17a393fb[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'
```

---

As I said, the operation of the application does not seem to be affected, but I would like some help solving this particular issue.

**Full MCVE:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class ConditionalColumnSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // TableView
        TableView<Bill> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Bill, Number> colAmountDue = new TableColumn<>("Amount Due");
        TableColumn<Bill, LocalDate> colDatePaid = new TableColumn<>("Date Paid");
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colAmountDue, colDatePaid);

        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // CellValueProperties
        colAmountDue.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().amountDueProperty());
        colDatePaid.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().datePaidProperty());

        // CellFactory for Date Paid column
        colDatePaid.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Bill, LocalDate>() {

            final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {

                    System.out.println(getTableRow()); // <-- This prints 'null' only once upon execution
                    Bill bill = (Bill) getTableRow().getItem();

                    if (item == null || bill.isDateChanged()) {
                        bill.datePaidProperty().bind(datePicker.valueProperty());
                        setGraphic(datePicker);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(new Label(bill.getDatePaid().toString()));
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        // Button to test data
        Button button = new Button("Print Values");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            for (Bill bill : tableView.getItems()) {
                System.out.println(bill);
            }
        });

        // Sample data
        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Bill(42.34, null),
                new Bill(894.99, null),
                new Bill(54.87, LocalDate.now()),
                new Bill(5.00, null),
                new Bill(123.68, LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 25))
        );

        root.getChildren().addAll(tableView, button);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class Bill {

    private DoubleProperty amountDue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> datePaid = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private BooleanProperty dateChanged = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public Bill(double amountDue, LocalDate datePaid) {
        this.amountDue.set(amountDue);
        this.datePaid.set(datePaid);

        // Listener to determine if the date has been changed
        this.datePaidProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dateChanged.set(true);
        });

    }

    public double getAmountDue() {
        return amountDue.get();
    }

    public void setAmountDue(double amountDue) {
        this.amountDue.set(amountDue);
    }

    public DoubleProperty amountDueProperty() {
        return amountDue;
    }

    public LocalDate getDatePaid() {
        return datePaid.get();
    }

    public void setDatePaid(LocalDate datePaid) {
        this.datePaid.set(datePaid);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> datePaidProperty() {
        return datePaid;
    }

    public boolean isDateChanged() {
        return dateChanged.get();
    }

    public void setDateChanged(boolean dateChanged) {
        this.dateChanged.set(dateChanged);
    }

    public BooleanProperty dateChangedProperty() {
        return dateChanged;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bill{" +
                "amountDue=" + amountDue +
                ", datePaid=" + datePaid +
                ", dateChanged=" + dateChanged +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't recall any part of the documentation mentioning that the `TableCell.tableRow` property is assigned before the `updateItem` method is called for the first time... BTW: I recommend ***unbinding*** the `datePaid` property once it's removed from the row belonging to the cell.

Comment: unrelated (again ;) - don't re-create controls in every call to updateItem, that's diametrically opposed to the idea of cell re-use ..

Comment: related: @fabian is fully on track, except that the null you are seeing is even specified in tableCell's tableRowProperty _The TableRow may be null early in the TableCell lifecycle, in the period between the TableCell being instantiated and being set into an owner TableRow._ ... javadoc is there for ... reading, just saying :))

Comment: Thank you, @fabian. Where would I unbind the property here?

Comment: note this comment is related to your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55962799/203657) .  _I had initially not wanted to use fixedCellSize() because someone on SO once told me to never specify an exact size for anything in a Scene ;)_ yeah, that someone is right <g> Why did you delete it? Your initial impulse is perfect, on hard-coding, you need to take care of adjusting that value whenever something that effects the row-height (borders, fonts, images ...) change, that can be quite a task ..

Comment: @kleopatra I deleted the question since it was no longer a problem. Thanks!